# ArcGIS Desktop 3D Analyst Line of Sight

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 3d-analyst, offset

I am trying to do some Line of Sight analysis on some points using 3D Analyst in ArcGIS Desktop. I have a set of points that I've made two copies of a feature class of, one to use as the observers and one to use as the targets (I want to look at line of sight between all the points looking at each other). I made sight lines between them and ran the LoS. The process worked fine. Here's the problem I'm having.

I have elevation data underneath as the raster layer, and am trying to use an OffsetA and OffsetB of 10m to replicate antennas at each point. When I build my sight lines and look at the height of those lines at the beginning and end, it reflects the 10m offsets. But when I run my LoS and look at the Z at the ends of those lines, it shows the height as the elevation data height and doesn't add in the offset.

I've tried using both projected and not-projected. I also tried making my sight lines 2D and 3D. Nothing makes the LoS lines raise up those 10m on the ends. I'm wondering now if those lines are supposed to show at a height with the offset like the sight lines or if they just show from the ground level?

Anyone have any ideas?